# How do i handle navigation Back button view hierarchy?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Here is the problem

1) Rootview controller - MYAssetVC-> Embedded with NavigationController here pushing for button to another Addfilevc.

2) Addfilevc Has dropdownTextfield It will push to another vc have tableview selected row will display in the textfield.

3)if i select another value from the dropdown textfield it will push to the vc again there i will select.

Navigation bar back button will navigate to all my view hierarchy i want to handle this one. if i go to same view it should navigate back only once that to the recent visit how to do this.

As i am new to iOS. give any suggestion.

Navigation from 1->2->3

navigation backbtn 3->2->1

if i navigate like this 1->2->3-> backbutton 3->2 again 2->3 backbutton 3->2 again 2->3

IF i navigate now using back it is displaying all my route path it should navigate like 1->2->3> and 3->2->1 if any number of times i perform actions in 2 & 3.

1,2,3 are view controllers.

Comment: your question is not very clear, could you explain it bit more clearly?

Comment: yes for sure i have view controller embedded with navigation okie? it has a dropdown which is implelemented with another vc if i select a value from that vc value will populate in another vc if i select again to change the dropdown value it will again populate if i navigate through back button all my hierarchy is showing i want to control that it should navigate only once

Comment: It is like 1->2->3 navigation will come 3->2->1 okie??  if i do my view like 1->2->3 back to 2 again 3 back 2 again 3 if click on navigation back now it should navigate my recent visit it shouldn't  navigate all my path how to control this

Comment: Are you using segues to navigate? or Code?

Comment: yes but not for navigation buttons segues there for controls in the vc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an IBAction for the back button and use popViewController.

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This will help you to go back one page. You have to write this in all the pages where there is a back button and you want to go back one page.

If you want to go back directly to rootViewController, try this:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

And if you want to pop to any specific viewController in the stack, you run a for loop to find the viewController you want to navigate to and then simply popToViewController, like this:

```
for (UIViewController *viewController in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[Addfilevc class]]) {
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps to clear your concept.

**EDIT**

In swift:

- The `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` will become `self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)`
- The `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];` will become `navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)`
- And the for loop will be as below:

You can use this if you are using storyboard

```
let switchViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view2") as ComposeViewController

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(switchViewController, animated: true)
```

And the for-in loop

```
if let viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers {
    for viewController in viewControllers {
        self.navigationController!.popToViewController(viewController, animated: true);
    } 
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: i used that but didn't work.please go through my question again i edited it. u will get my requirement

Comment: can u pls post a swift code that for loop code if u don't mind

Comment: Thank you very much that is the answer but if i give poprootviewcontroller app is crashing

Comment: I have edited my answer for the swift code. And for the crash, there might be an exception. Can you use an exception debugger and see what the exception might be?

Comment: Thank you very much and also i need 1 more help how u people use date picker  i mean u go with a new view or through popup which is better way for ui